# How do I capture multiple input text fields data into a list and iterate it over using JSTL?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

I am trying to do below. In my JSP, I created a table with heading such as "Oct 2013", "Nov 2013", ....for next 12 months. i.e. till "Sept 2014".

These months and years should current, for e.g. if the month is Nov 2013 then the system should detect is Nov 2013 and it should add 12 months till next year Oct 2014.

There are 12 input fields (one for each month), and they are in a single row.
The user can add a new row dynamically in this table and enter can enter quantity values into those text fields for any of the input fields for the months.

```
<table border="1" class="atable" align="center" width="85%">
<tr>
<th>LRN Required</th>
<th>Oct 2013</th>
<th>Nov 2013</th>
<th>Dec 2013</th>
<th>Jan 2014</th>
<th>Feb 2014</th>
<th>Mar 2014</th>
<th>Apr 2014</th>
<th>May 2014</th>
<th>June 2014</th>
<th>Jul 2014</th>
<th>Aug 2014</th>
<th>Sept 2014</th>

</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td><input type="text" size="4"/></td>
<td><input type="text" size="4"/></td>
<td><input type="text" size="4"/></td>
<td><input type="text" size="4"/></td>
<td><input type="text" size="4"/></td>
<td><input type="text" size="4"/></td>
<td><input type="text" size="4"/></td>
<td><input type="text" size="4"/></td>
<td><input type="text" size="4"/></td>
<td><input type="text" size="4"/></td>
<td><input type="text" size="4"/></td>
<td><input type="text" size="4"/></td>

</tr>
</table>
```

I am using Spring MVC and would like to use JSTL for this functionality.

Model class:

```
public class Forecast {

private int id;
private int quantity;
private String lastUpdatedBy;
private String rateCenter;
.....
getters and setters here...

}

My controller class looks like below...

@Controller
@SessionAttributes("forecastModel")
public class ForecastController extends PasBaseController {

    @Autowired
    HttpServletRequest request;


    protected static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(ForecastController.class);

    private static final String FRCST_MODEL = "forecastModel";


    @RequestMapping(value="preforecast.do")
    public String setUpPreforecast(final Model model, HttpServletRequest req) 
    {

        User user = WebUtil.getSignInUser(req);
        ForecastModel forecastModel = new ForecastModel();

        log.debug("User Info.");
        log.debug(user.getUserId());
        log.debug(user.getFullName());
        log.debug(user.getPhone());

        Long id = (long) 15260;

        List<Long> userNpaList = null;
        List<String> userOcnList = null;

        try{
            if(user != null)
            {

                userNpaList = PasServicesUtils.getAllNpaAssocForUserId(id);
                userOcnList = PasServicesUtils.geAllOcnAssocForUserId(id);

                model.addAttribute("userNpaList", userNpaList);
                model.addAttribute("userOcnList", userOcnList);

                forecastModel.setUserNpaList(userNpaList);
                forecastModel.setUserOcnList(userOcnList);

                model.addAttribute("forecastModel", forecastModel);
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            log.error("List is NULL");
        }

        log.debug("Exiting setUpPreforecast() method.");

        return PasConstants.PREFORECAST;
    }



    @RequestMapping(value = {PasConstants.FORECAST})
    public String continueFromPreforecast(@ModelAttribute("forecastModel") ForecastModel forecastModel, Errors errors, HttpServletRequest request, final ModelMap modelMap) throws Exception
    {

    User user = WebUtil.getSignInUser(request);


    modelMap.addAttribute("ocn", forecastModel.getOcn());
    modelMap.addAttribute("phone", user.getPhone());
    modelMap.addAttribute("fax", user.getFax());

    modelMap.addAttribute("email", user.getEmail());

    modelMap.addAttribute("forecastRptDt", PasDate.displayDayMonthYearFormat2(new PasDate()));

    modelMap.addAttribute("npa", forecastModel.getNpa());



    List<String> rateCntrAbbrList;
    rateCntrAbbrList = PasServicesUtils.getAllRtCntrsAssocForNpa(forecastModel.getNpa());



    if(rateCntrAbbrList != null && rateCntrAbbrList.size() > 0)
    {
        modelMap.addAttribute("rateCntrAbbrList", rateCntrAbbrList);
    }

   //modelMap.addAttribute("rateCtr", forecastModel.getRtCntrId().
   //validateForecastData(forecastModel, errors, user);
   if (errors.hasErrors())
   {
       return PasConstants.PREFORECAST;

   }

    return PasConstants.FORECAST;
}

@RequestMapping(value = {PasConstants.FORECAST_SUCCESS}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String submitForecast(@ModelAttribute("forecastModel") ForecastModel forecastModel, Errors errors, HttpServletRequest request, final ModelMap modelMap) throws Exception
{

/* I am trying to access the months related data i.e. quantiy that user entered through the text fields in the above table. */

    ForecastServiceClient.createForecast(forecastModel);

    return PasConstants.FORECAST_SUCCESS;
}

My question is, how to capture user entered data into a list and pass it to the the controller class?

Do i need to create a separate class for 12 months and a year? 
Do I need to access them using a public List<String> getMonthsAndYear() {..} inside my 'Forecast' class since these months and a current year will be a part of this class only.

How do i iterate through list of months inside the JSP using JSTL? I do not want to use scriplet here.

Please, help me how to approach this problem so that the data entered by the user into input fields can be posted to the controller method for further processing.

Thanks,
```

Answer (score 0):

Model

```
public class Forecast {
      ...     
      private List<String> sections;
      /* getters/setters */
    }
```

controller

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/test.do")
public String someController(@ModelAttribute Forecast  forecast ) {
  /* Do whatever with your  */
}
```

Comment: where is name attribute in code <input type="text" size="4"/>  name should be name of getter of the model

Comment: John, I am using <form:input...> and <spring:bind..> as below...<spring:bind path="forecastModel.forecastMonthsBeanList[${status.index}].quantities[0] " >
<td><form:input path="${status.expression}" size="4"/></td> 
</spring:bind>

Answer (score 0):

John, thanks for your reply. I did some research and found that .... can bind a dynamic list. I modified my controller class, I updated my model class and added a list getter and setter methods as you mentioned above, also, I am now using AutoPopulatingList of spring framework to modify the list and pass it to the JSP via modelMap.addAttribute("forecastMonthsBeanList", forecastModel.getForecastMonthsBeanList()), from Controller method. My issue is,however, on the jsp side, I have this jQuery function which is supposed to create a new row every time it is clicked. i.e. the row contains 12 input text boxes/fields and upon single click it is supposed to create 12 new text boxes in a new row, but, it does not work. I am not sure how to make this jQuery function work with spring:bind when "add row" button is clicked. My 1st row is having 12 input text boxes with default values assigned as '0' from a bean declared as a getter and setter in the model class. Below is my jQuery function and JSP code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("document").ready(function(){
$(".alternativeRow").btnAddRow({oddRowCSS:"oddRow",evenRowCSS:"evenRow"});
$(".delRow").btnDelRow();
});
</script>
```

Oct 2013Nov 2013Dec 2013Jan 2014Feb 2014Mar 2014Apr 2014
May 2014June 2014Jul 2014Aug 2014Sept 2014








                   
                   
                   
                   
                   
                   
                   
                   
                   
                   
                   
                   

-----